# element.style in template for joomla

Tags: styles, joomla3.0

iam having an issue with the element.style. Made a custom template and it work fine however when i add an article with a read more button to the front end the titel doesnt show properly, when i check on firebugs it show me Scuba diving at

It generate from its own, it should be the size of h3 but it stay small.
As iam a super newbie i need your help to remove the auto resize of 11px.

Could someone help me please.
Have a look on:
http://jd.justdiving.net/our-diving-centers

You can see the titel:
Scuba diving at
The Paradise Cove Boutique Hotel in Anse la Raie

THank you for your help

Comment: I can not see that page, and it seems that is already solved.